# Chosen in bootstrap popover not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

When i open the popover for the first time the chosen drop down menu works great, but when i close and then open it again it doesn't work, it kind of freezes.

**Here is what i am exactly doing:**

I have 4-5 links on my website, when the use clicks on any link a popover opens.
User fill in details in input fields, chooses values in select box etc.
Now when user clicks on save i close the popover and save the html of popover.
Now when i open the popover again, every value is same as last time filled by user.
But for my chosen, it freezes to the value the last the was taken in it, and i can not select any value.

Comment: Without code we probably can not help you.
Eventually try this : 
Your jQuery **must** be in first (before javascript) when you call them

Comment: I am making a fiddle for it, i will post it as soon as its done.

Comment: i think you are recreating the html elements all together. try re-initializing the chosen plugin each time you recreate the html

Comment: If i re initialize the chosen plugin, the multiple values that the user chose, will also be removed.

Comment: I am unable to run it in my jsfiddle, can some one make a fiddle for something like this.